# JavaScript How to loop through unique values of nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to loop through all unique values from a nested object. It seems like something like this should be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried this

`const result = [...new Set(events.flatMap(({tags}) => tags))].sort()`

And then when I echo out `{ result }` I ultimately get the output of unique values. But I want to use these values in the application. Somehow wrap each value in a `<button>` or something.

Below is my test object. Each item has an array of tags, and I want to be able to dynamically list out all unique tags.

I'd be very grateful for any help here.

Thanks in advance.

```
const events = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Event 1",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Event 2",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Event 3",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 3", "tag 2"]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Event 4",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 5", "tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Event 5",
        tags: ["tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Event 6",
        tags: ["tag 2", "tag 3"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a forEach loop?  From you example,  
`[...new Set(events.flatMap(({tags}) => tags))].sort().forEach((tag) => {
// do what you would like to do with unique tags
console.log(item)
) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
  const events = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Event 1",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Event 2",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Event 3",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 3", "tag 2"]
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Event 4",
        tags: ["tag 1", "tag 5", "tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Event 5",
        tags: ["tag 3"]
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "Event 6",
        tags: ["tag 2", "tag 3"]
    }
  ];  
  const result = [...new Set(events.flatMap(({tags}) => tags))].sort();
  return (
    <div>
      {
        result.map((tag,i) => <h1 key={i}>{tag}</h1>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```